# Make title bold in infowindow

Tags: javascript, html, xml

Hi experts I just want to ask on how to make the title of my info window bold or strong.  My code is like this. Help me experts.

```
var name = markerElem.getAttribute('name');
var infowincontent = document.createElement('div');
              var strong = document.createElement('strong'); 
              strong.textContent = name
              infowincontent.appendChild(strong);
              infowincontent.appendChild(document.createElement('br'));
```

But it doesn't make the name bold in my infowindow.

Answer (score 1):

You can use html along with google map info window like this:

```
var contentString = '<strong>My title</strong>';
var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
      content: contentString
});
```

Also, the complete example you will find here: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/infowindow-simple

Answer (score 0):

I just added this to my code and it made it bold already.

```
strong.style.fontWeight = 'bold';
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<body>
<div id="wrapper" name="yourname">hello</div>
<script>
// makerelem
var markerElem = document.getElementById('wrapper');

var name = markerElem.getAttribute('name');
var infowincontent = document.createElement('div');
var strong = document.createElement('strong');
strong.textContent = name
infowincontent.appendChild(strong);
infowincontent.appendChild(document.createElement('br'));

// add in document
document.body.appendChild(infowincontent);

</script>
</body>
```

Code result:
[image: Code result]